# Edit Settings in SQL Server Configuration Manager Command Line

Tags: sql-server, command-line, ssms

i'm looking for a way to edit properties in SQL Server Configuration Manager via command line or with a batch script or something. I know I can stop and restart a service, but I want to update the Named Pipes property (as an example). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: i only want to know the server name ! is there any command ? or vbscript ?